# Kill all ffmpeg processes which open repeatedly c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, process

i'm new to C# and i'm trying to create a tool based on ffmpeg to convert video.
As title, i did google search and find out many ways to kill ffmpeg process, but in my case, for example i got 10 videos, which means 10 ffmpeg processes will be created one by one. If i closed form during 1st video, 9 others will be created sequently in background.

Is there any effective ways to stop ffmpeg to create process ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand your question, but I hope one of the two approaches might help.

**Approach 1:**

[Here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2748) I found a solution how to stop all ffmpeg processes on the local machine.

```
/// <summary>
/// Stops all ffmpeg processes on the local machine
/// </summary>
private void StopCapturing()
{
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "taskkill",
            Arguments = "/F /IM ffmpeg.exe",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

**Approach 2:**

For each ffmpeg.exe process you start, you can save the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). With the PID you are able to kill every instance of ffmpeg.exe you started before.

```
/// <summary>
/// Starts a new process on the local machine. Returns the PID of the started process
/// </summary>
/// <param name="processName"></param>
/// <param name="arguments"></param>
private int StartProcess(string processName, string arguments)
{
    // Initializes the process
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = processName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    // Starts the process
    process.Start();

    return process.Id;
}

/// <summary>
/// Kills the process that equals the passed PID
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pid"></param>
private void KillProcess(int pid)
{
    Process process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
    process.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish, but here is the method used for killing a process in C#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx